# META tag is not working in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I am developing a web app using **sails.js**.

Here I want to render a page which **url** is specified as **META** tag in another page.

Code:

1. In controller I am passing view variables.

   `var campaignVars = {
        layout: false,
        shared_link: campaign.shared_link,
        page_content: campaign.page_content
    };
    return res.render('campaign/target-page', campaignVars);`
2. In view file 'campaign/taget-page.ejs'

   `<html lang="en-US">`

    `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url="http://google.com/">`

   `<body>
       loading...`

   `</html>`

But it's no being redirected to "http://google.com/"

Kindly suggest what to do to get the required result.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I see there is an error in your `meta`

Remove the quote between `url=` and `http`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://google.com/">
```

Why are you using `res.render`
as you can directly pass object without file and controller name under the function with sails controller format.

```
return res.view(campaignVars);
```